# Repeated loading of same page Makes the Angular App Slow

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I have an Angular app based on Angular7 and there has been a very strange issue I am getting in the code.

When I load the same page multiple times then the app starts responding extremely slow and I am even unable to type in the form after repeated loading of same page.

This is not specific to only one page rather all the pages makes the app slow after repeated use of multiple pages.

Now, the concern is how to detect which code is creating this issue?

I tried to update the Angular packages but nothing helps.

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "apex",
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "7.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.16.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.21",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "bourbon": "5.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "file-droppa": "^1.8.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.2",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "7.0.1",
    "node-sass": "4.7.2",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.1.2",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "1.4.2",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "screenfull": "3.3.1",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/node": "9.4.7",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.0.0",
    "protractor": "5.3.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "5.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you subscribing to `Observables`? If yes, do you unsubscribe? That's one of possible problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too generic, you need to debug your code and see if you have any synchronic requests that might get stuck.

Comment: Resolved - a function was executing again and again with deadlock